# Second script file not working

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript files linking to one html file, and depending on the order I put them, the second one does not work.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>J2EE</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="J2EE quiz page"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="html, j2ee, J2EE"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Wing Hang Khoo"/>
    <!-- Reference to external style -->
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="scripts/enhancements.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/quiz.js"></script>
</head>
```

JS 1:

```
function x(){
*validating questions codes*
}

function init(){
var regForm = document.getElementById("regForm");
regForm.onsubmit = gradeTest;
}

window.onload = init;
```

JS 2:

```
function y(){
*timer code*
}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

Not sure if it is because both have `window.onload` function.

Comment: A property can only hold one value. You can't have two functions assigned to `window.onload`. Use `.addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> window.onload = init;
>
> window.onload = function () {
> ```

In one script you assigned a function to `onload`. In the next you overwrote it with a new value.

Avoid using such properties directly, use `addEventListener` and friends instead.

```
addEventListener("load", init);
addEventListener("load", function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```